# scatter plot of same variable across different conditions with ggplot facet_grid?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to correlate the same column of a dataframe for points with distinct row values. For example, in the `iris` dataframe, I'd like to make three scatter plots comparing `Petal.Length` of `virginica` with that of `versicolor`, `setosa` with `virginica` and `versicolor` with `setosa`. I want it to appear just like a normal `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap` plot. For example, I can do:

`ggplot(iris) + geom_point(aes(x=Petal.Length, y=Petal.Length)) + facet_grid(~Species)`

This is not what I want, since it's plotting `Petal.Length` of each species against itself, but I want the plot to appear like this, except where I handcode which species to compare to what other species. How can this be done in `ggplot`? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to group the data first. I'd do something like this:

```
# get Petal.Length for each species separately    
df1 <- subset(iris, Species == "virginica", select=c(Petal.Length, Species))
df2 <- subset(iris, Species == "versicolor", select=c(Petal.Length, Species))
df3 <- subset(iris, Species == "setosa", select=c(Petal.Length, Species))

# construct species 1 vs 2, 2  vs 3 and 3 vs 1 data
df <- data.frame(x=c(df1$Petal.Length, df2$Petal.Length, df3$Petal.Length), 
y = c(df2$Petal.Length, df3$Petal.Length, df1$Petal.Length), 
grp = rep(c("virginica.versicolor", "versicolor.setosa", "setosa.virginica"), each=50))
df$grp <- factor(df$grp)

# plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(colour=grp)) + facet_wrap( ~ grp)
```

This results in:

[image]

Comment: Is there no simpler way to do this? I don't want to use `factor` since I am using rpy2 and it's getting complex. I can make any dataframe, but want to avoid `factor`. I guess `grp` can be a regular column, without being a factor, right?

Comment: I don't know about `rpy2`. And what do you mean you don't want to use factor? A facetting requires a factor'd variable.

Comment: One word of caution: In the `iris` data, there is no basis for pairing or matching observations of Petal.Length made on different individual flowers of different species. In this plot you have randomly (but opaquely) made pairs and plotted them.

Comment: @bdemarest, totally right! I missed to spot that point and mention in my post. Thanks a lot for pointing out.

Comment: @bdemarest: fair enough, iris was a bad example, in my data there is a pairing so Arun's solution is what I was looking for.  I thought there might be a way to do this without regrouping into a new df but I guess ggplot really relies on reading the info from the df

Comment: @user248237: There may well be a simpler approach. I was experimenting with `dcast()` (from reshape2) and `ggpairs()` (from GGally) when I realized that it just didn't work with the iris data.

Answer (score 12):

Your question seems to be about comparing a single variable measured on many individuals that fall into multiple categories. Given your example using the `iris` dataset, a scatterplot is probably not a useful visualization.

Here I offer several univariate visualizations available in `ggplot2`. I hope one of these is helpful:

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_1 = ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, colour=Species)) +
         geom_density() +
         labs(title="Density plots")

plot_2 = ggplot(iris, aes(x=Petal.Length, fill=Species)) +
         geom_histogram(colour="grey30", binwidth=0.15) +
         facet_grid(Species ~ .) +
         labs(title="Histograms")

plot_3 = ggplot(iris, aes(y=Petal.Length, x=Species)) +
         geom_point(aes(colour=Species),
                    position=position_jitter(width=0.05, height=0.05)) +
         geom_boxplot(fill=NA, outlier.colour=NA) +
         labs(title="Boxplots")

plot_4 = ggplot(iris, aes(y=Petal.Length, x=Species, fill=Species)) +
         geom_dotplot(binaxis="y", stackdir="center", binwidth=0.15) +
         labs(title="Dot plots")

library(gridExtra)
part_1 = arrangeGrob(plot_1, plot_2, heights=c(0.4, 0.6))
part_2 = arrangeGrob(plot_3, plot_4, nrow=2)
parts_12 = arrangeGrob(part_1, part_2, ncol=2, widths=c(0.6, 0.4))
ggsave(file="plots.png", parts_12, height=6, width=10, units="in")
```

[image]